# Spring Java POST endpoint that can have a field be different data types

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, overloading

I'm working on a Java Spring Boot HTTP Service application. I currently have a POST endpoint that I have defined inside of a `@RestController`. This controller, called `processRequest` takes an object called `Info` with the `@RequestBody` annotation.

Right now, I have it setup where a user can send JSON based on the `Info` class that I defined like this:

```
//Sample JSON Payload
{
   "name": "Bob",
   "age": 26,
   "hobby": biking
}

//Sample Object
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Info {
   public final String name;
   public final int age;
   public final String hobby
}
```

What I want to do know is respond to the situation where one of the fields is sent as a different datatype. For example:

```
//JSON payload with different datatype for a field
{
   "name": "Bob",
   age: 26,
   "hobby": ["biking", "hiking"]   //This is supposed to be a string but it's an array.
}
```

Is it possible to keep the endpoint properties the same but handle different data types? Maybe I can create another class where the fields are different and spring will automatically create the one that matches the input? I'm curious for what the best approach to this problem would be.

Comment: omit the single string value and just use array

Comment: @MarcStroebel Some people/applications are already using the endpoint with a single value and I don't want to change all of them to arrays if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, where the hobby could either be a single value or multiple values, I would rely on the Jackson `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` deserialization feature.

This can be configured application-wide within application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.accept-single-value-as-array=true
```

Or this can be enabled for a specific field:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Info {
   public final String name;
   public final int age;
   @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
   public final List<String> hobby
}
```

---

For more complex cases, Jackson recommends that you write a wrapper with a specific type field to provide a hint of which type it should deserialize. For example:

```java
public class InfoWrapper {
    private String type;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "type", include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
    @JsonSubTypes(value = { 
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PersonInfo.class, name = "person")
    })
    private Info info;
}

public interface Info {}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonInfo implements Info {
   public final String name;
   public final int age;
   public final String hobby
}
```

So, if you want to send a JSON containing `PersonInfo`, you can use the following JSON:

```json
{
  "type": "person",
  "info": {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 26,
    "hobby": "biking"
  }
}
```

---

If you need more advanced control over what you want to do, you can write a custom deserializer and apply it with the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation.

Comment: This is a perfect response. I didn't even think to check out the underlying Jackson parser. The Annotation method seems to be good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonNode` for the field which changes. As below:

```
public class Info {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public JsonNode hobby;
    
    
    @Schema(description = "")
    @Valid
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<String> getHobbies() {

      // if hobby is array create Java object and return
      // else if hobby is String create List, add the string to it and return it.
      // or some other solution of your choice and requirement
      
    }
}
```